# redshift query to get desired output

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, amazon-redshift

In redshift for a provided dataset for a restaurant

Every Dish_id is being assigned to a category 
So based on the distinct orders which are being palced 
I need to find out  for a provided primary dish what all other items went along with it
primary item (every distinct item of that restaurant will act as a primary dish once)

Currently i am able to do it for a single dish_id and getting its contribution

```
Select category_name,count(category_name) from  (
```

`Select order_id,dish_id,dish_name,category_id,category_name from abc

where order_id in (Select distinct order_id from abc where dish_name='Paneer_pizza' and restaurant_id=1) 
group by order_id,dish_id,dish_name,category_id,category_name
order by category_name
)
group by category_name`

Question's

> How can i print Panner_pizza in the outer query along with category_name and count?
>
> How can i pass all the dish_name present in that restaurant in inner query 
>   and get the contribution for all the dishes along with count for all the categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you want...you might need two queries. But I think an inner query like this might help. This will filter the results to just the primary dish and restaurant that you are interested in and add the primary dish to each record in the order.

```
select a.order_id, primary_dish, dish_id, dish_name, category_id, category_name
from abc a
inner join (
    Select distinct order_id, dish_name as primary_dish
    from abc
    where dish_name='Paneer_pizza' and restaurant_id=1
) b on b.order_id = a.order_id
where primary_dish != dish_name --optionally exclude the primary dish record
```

So count of other dish categories for the primary dish would be:

```
with dishes as (
    select a.order_id, primary_dish, dish_id, dish_name, category_id, category_name
    from abc a
    inner join (
        Select distinct order_id, dish_name as primary_dish
        from abc
        where dish_name='Paneer_pizza' and restaurant_id=1
    ) b on b.order_id = a.order_id
    where primary_dish != dish_name --optionally exclude the primary dish record
)
select primary_dish, category_name, count(*) from dishes
group by primary_dish, category_name
```

I think this might be what you actually want. This gives all the dishes in the restaurant treating each as a primary dish and then gives dishes ordered with the primary, their category and the total number of orders placed that included the secondary dish:

```
with dishes as (
    select a.order_id, primary_dish, dish_id, dish_name, category_id, category_name
    from abc a
    inner join (
        Select distinct order_id, dish_name as primary_dish
        from abc
        where restaurant_id=1
    ) b on b.order_id = a.order_id
    where primary_dish != dish_name --optionally exclude the primary dish record
)
select primary_dish, dish_name, category_name, count(*) from dishes
group by primary_dish, dish_name, category_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @systemjack 
it worked like a charm 

This is exactly was lookin for ,
tught abt it whole day but was unable to figure it out 
really appriciate your efforts for expalining it with detailed query
and thaks again